# Deductive proof with Hilbert system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Given b→a, and⌝(a→⌝b)

I'm trying to derive b. Obviously I can use some identities (like De Morgan) to show that ⌝(a→⌝b) is equivalent a∧b. However, I'd like to avoid using any other connectives than → and⌝, and rather prove using rules like Contrapositive, Transitivity, Double negation, Modus Ponens, etc (those of Hilbert system).

I struggled to prove this, but couldn't, as easy as it may seem. I'd appreciate your help please.

Comment: Not sure what rules you have.  'Hilbert systems' typically don;t have anything like Double Negation.  And what do you mean by Transitivity?  Can you please just add the rules to your Post so we can provide an informed response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Mendelson's First Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems) :

1) $\lnot b \to (a \to \lnot b)$.

Use the same axiom to derive, by *Modus Ponens*, from 2nd premise :

2) $\lnot b \to \lnot (a \to \lnot b)$.

Use 1) and 2) and Mendelson's Third Axiom to derive, by *Modus Ponens* :

> $b$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\neg (a \rightarrow \neg b) \iff \neg(\neg a \vee\neg b) \iff \neg\neg a \wedge \neg\neg b \iff a\wedge b
$$

Comment: Thank you, however as I said, I'm not allowed to use ∨, ∧ connectives